# How to perform an SQL insert in Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to insert data in to a table with an auto increment primary key.
My table structure is like this:

```
int:PK 
varchar:Item_ID 
varchar:Item_name 
int:FK_type
```

When I try the prepared statement:

```
prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into Inventory values (?, ?, ?);");
```

I get this Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing    database (table Inventory has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:42)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:404)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:399)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:383)
    at org.checkout.CheckInventory.<init>(CheckInventory.java:58)
    at org.checkout.main.main(main.java:18)
```

When I try executing the statement:

```
stat.executeUpdate("insert into Inventory (Item_ID, Item_name, FK_type ) values ('TP1', 'NX Tripod 1', 2)");
```

I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_MISUSE]  Library used incorrectly (out of memory)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152)
    at org.checkout.CheckInventory.insertItem(CheckInventory.java:73)
    at org.checkout.CheckInventory$1.actionPerformed(CheckInventory.java:25)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I get a [SQLITE_MISUSE] error when I try to add four columns in the statement.

Here is the method that inputs the data

```
protected static void insertItem() throws Exception {

    stat.execute("insert into Inventory (Item_ID, Item_name, FK_type ) values ('TP1', 'NX Tripod 1', 2)");


}
```

Comment: Seems to be the same manifestation: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/51/javasqlsqlexception-sqlite_misuse-library

Comment: Please post full code you're using to insert data.

Answer (score 1):

Your table has four columns and your inserts are only inserting three values.  Try removing a column from the table, or alternatively inserting four values when inserting a row.